# $GEM is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, osx-yosemite

Suddenly I can't run rspec or guard anymore. I even did a checkout on an old commit where I know I had some tests running. Same error there.

```
$ git checkout known-working-commit && bundle && rspec spec
.../ruby-2.2.3@solidus/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:304:in 
`block in replace_gem': rspec-core is not part of the bundle. 
Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I get the same error if I run `rspec` and `guard`.
Having a look at the PATH exposed by `rvm info`, I see that guard is available at `/Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/bin/guard`. 
$PATH also has `/Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/bin` as it's first entry.
Any idea what might have gone wrong? I thought that by having a directory listed first in PATH would give it precedence over the other directories listed. How come I get the `"bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:304:in block in replace_gem': rspec-core is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile"` error?

I'm running OS X 10.10.5 and ZSH.

My test section from **Gemfile**

```
 19 group :test do
 20   gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
 21   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4'
 22   gem 'capybara-screenshot'
 23   gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3'
 24   gem 'email_spec'
 25   gem 'launchy'
 26   gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks', '~>1.0.2'
 27   gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
 28   gem 'rspec-its'
 29   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
 30   gem 'simplecov'
 31   gem 'webmock', '1.8.11'
 32   gem 'poltergeist'
 33   gem 'timecop'
 34   gem 'with_model'
 35   gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
 36 end
```

The same branch works as expect on my work computer. Which makes me think there is some environment settings that are messing things up.

Comment: Have you done what it said? Is `rspec` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, I got rspec in Gemfile and I've run bundle. It works if I check out the code on an other computer. I think it's some environment specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just having the `gem` either in the `PATH` or `GEM_PATH` is not enough. Your application needs to `require` it. Adding it to the `Gemfile` and bundling it ensures that the `bundler` requires it for you.

Ensure that the `rspec` or `rspec-rails` (if rails based application) is included in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: You can see my Gemfile in my main post.